# How to access element

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I am beginner Rails developer.  I tried all Stack Overflow answers, but I have had no success.

My Nokogiri element is:

```
#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3ff66cdbf144 name="busstop" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf0a4 name="id" value="7c7b5df6-1657-11e5-94a5-00235443ce54">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf07c name="name" value=" Еманжелинск">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf068 name="region" value="Челябинская Область мес">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf054 name="automated">]>
```

I need to access:

```
attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf0a4 name="id" value="7c7b5df6-1657-11e5-94a5-00235443ce54">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf07c name="name" value=" Еманжелинск">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf068 name="region" value="Челябинская Область мес">
```

I have tried these:

```
stop.attribute("attributes")
stop.xpath("//busstop//attributes")
stop.xpath("//busstop//attributes/*")
stop[:attributes]
stop["attributes"]
stop.attributes
```

`stop` is a temp variable on simple `each` loop.

I saw attributes is an another Nokogiri hash.

How can I solve it?

Comment: This file is so large.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We don't need to know the Nokogiri element. We need the minimal example of your input XML and the minimal example of your code that demonstrates the problem. As is, you're asking us to reverse engineer the XML which wastes our time, and yours because we'd probably come up with something different. Please read "[ask]" and edit your question supplying the needed information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your problem is, but it should work this way:

```
stop.attributes # returns something like {id: "...", name: "Еманжелинск"...}

stop.attribute_nodes # returns something like [#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3ff66cdbf0a4 ...]

stop.attribute['name'] # returns "Еманжелинск"
```

If `stop.attributes` doesn't work then check what is the class of the `stop` variable, probably that's neither a `Nokogiri::XML::Node`, neither an `Nokogiri::XML::Element`. Also check whether the `stop` actually is a `<busstop>` element (its `name` should return 'busstop').